# Akka IO(Tcp) get reason of CommandFailed

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following example of Actor using IO(Tcp)
https://gist.github.com/flirtomania/a36c50bd5989efb69a5f

For the sake of experiment I've run it twice, so it was trying to bind to 803 port. Obviously I've got an error.

Question: How can I get the reason why "CommandFailed"? In application.conf I have enabled slf4j and debug level of logs, then I've got an error in my logs.

`DEBUG akka.io.TcpListener - Bind failed for TCP channel on endpoint [localhost/127.0.0.1:803]: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`

But why is that only debug level? I do not want to enable all ActorSystem to log their events, I want to get the reason of CommandFailed event (like java.lang.Exception instance which I could make `e.printStackTrace()`)

Something like:
`case c @ CommandFailed => val e:Exception = c.getReason()`

Maybe it's not the Akka-way? How to get diagnostic info then?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do - find the PID that still keeps living and then kill it.

On a Mac -

lsof -i : portNumber
then 
kill -9 PidNumber

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you have 2 questions.

1. if you ran the same code simultaneously, bot actors are trying to bind to the same port (in your case, `803`) which is not possible unless the bound one unbinds and closes the connection so that the other one can bind.
2. you can import `akka.event.Logging` and put `val log = Logging(context.system, this)` at the beginning of your actors, which will log all the activities of your actors and ... 
   it also shows the name of the actor,corresponding actor system and host+port (if you are using akka-cluster).

wish that helps